# Concentration change due to different pumping efficiency

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I send a mixture of two gases (5% (v/v) initial concentration) into a chamber. The chamber is pumped to a low pressure, but the efficiency of the pumping for both gases is not the same (because of different molecular weights). The pumping speed (S1) of one gas is 77% of pumping speed of the other (S2).

How can I calculate the new concentration?

Comment: It depends what you mean by pumping speed. Typically the pressure will fall in a roughly exponential fashion as you pump, probably with a non-exponential tail at very low pressures.

Comment: Pumping speed (as I found in literature) is dV/dt. Typically in [l/s].

Comment: You treat them independently. One gas is being pumped faster than the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could treat this as a case of effusion of the mixture of two gases through a small hole in the chamber.  See Graham's Law (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_law).

The pumping speed is equivalent to a rate of effusion (number n of moles per unit time t) for each gas :
$\frac{dn}{dt}= -kn $
where k is a constant depending on type of gas.  This has the solution
$n(t)=n(0)e^{-kt}$.

The concentration of each gas decreases exponentially with different factors k related by
$\frac{k_1}{k_2}=\sqrt{\frac{m_2}{m_1}}$.

The details of your experiment are not very clear, so I shall not take this any further.  If you want further help, please provide more details, along with an attempt to apply the above formulas to your situation.